# Google Sheet script to delete rows based on individual cell and array

Tags: arrays, google-apps-script, google-sheets, rows

I'm struggling to make a script to delete corresponding rows to another sheet. Ideally, I want to be able to run a script that deletes the matching entries from Sheet 1 Supplier and Jobs and sheet 2. The problem is that some Jobs will be matching with other suppliers. Any help would be truly appreciated!

An example sheet:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1G5vUPF6H1WWlHICDd92SMg44QfPUObil8A2Ocu_usm4/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Completed Sheet]
[image: Pending Sheet]

Note You need to update your completed sheet to this format

```js
const ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById(sheetID);


function deleteRowMain() {
  //data with completed Results
  let ws_1 = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1");
  let ws_2 = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet2");
  let data_completed = ws_1.getDataRange().getValues();
  let data_pending = ws_2.getDataRange().getValues();

  //nameIndex and job index on completed sheet
  let nameIndex = 2;
  let jobIndex = 3;

  for (let i = 0; i < data_completed.length; i++) {
    let row = data_completed[i];
    deleteRow_(row[nameIndex - 1], row[jobIndex - 1])
  }
}

function deleteRow_(value_1, value_2) {
  //nameIndex and job index on pending sheet
  let nameIndex = 2;
  let jobIndex = 3;

  let ws = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet2");
  let data = ws.getDataRange().getValues();
  for (let i = data.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    let row = data[i];
    if (row[nameIndex - 1] == value_1 && row[jobIndex - 1] == value_2) {
      //delets row if 'Value1' and 'value2' matches
      ws.deleteRow(i + 1);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much for this, it's really close to what I want. This is basically where I got to, but the format is going to be reports and/or invoices, so I can't just be repeating the client's name every line, is there a way to set that as the first value of the array throughout?

Comment: Edit: I ended up just creating a hidden column to achieve the same result, would still be interested in whether it's possible!